# date_diff delivers wrong differences?

Tags: php, date, datediff

I am using date_diff to get the days in between two days as followed:

```
 //DATE
 $current_date = date_create(date("m.d.y"));
 $move_date = date_create($move['moving_day']);

/* Difference between Moving and Current Date */
$difference1 = date_diff($current_date, $move_date);
$date_difference = $difference1->format('%a');
```

The date is 2016-05-30 and the current is 2016-05-22 but it shows me 7, but it should give me 8.

print_r give me that

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-05-22 05:22:16.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-05-30 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note those `05:22:16` hours/minutes/seconds in your current date..... now how many whole days are there between `2016-05-22 05:22:16` and `2016-05-30 00:00:00`? and how many part days?

Comment: If you specify `$current_date = date_create('today');`, then you'll get `00:00:00` today rather than the current time

Comment: True that. Thanks! date_create sounded like the right function, but I guess I have to use annother one or just extract the date.

Comment: Why do you think date_create() is the wrong function.... it works perfectly well when you tell it the correct value to use.... it creates a DateTime object; and you're simply using it ambiguously so that it populates the current time, the difference between `today` and `now`

Comment: There is no PHP type that is purely date without time, nor any type that is time without date.... same as the real world

Answer (score 1):

if you want to don't depend on time of days, shift time to 00:00:00 in such way:

```
$current_date = date_create(date("m.d.y"))->modify('midnight');
$move_date = date_create($move['moving_day'])->modify('midnight');
```

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct, if you change current time to 2016-05-30 06:00:00 it will return 8 days

Comment: thanks. I thought date_create just creates the date, not time. Is there a function just for the date?

Comment: try $current_date = date("Y").'-'.date("m").'-'.date('d').' '.date('G').':'.date('i').':'.date('s');